# Hiding route parameters

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I am learning nodejs with express and i am creating my first single page application with the help of knockoutjs, i have a lot of routes and i am looking for a way to hide the parameters in the Url other than encoding them, if i have header links like :

```
http://www.mywebapp.com/login
http://www.mywebapp.com/logout
http://www.mywebapp.com/signup
http://www.mywebapp.com/users/username
http://www.mywebapp.com/users/1-8
```

can i still make those links appear as

```
http://www.mywebapp.com
```

no matter what the route to be called is?

if not possible can someone please explain why?

my application is completely ajax driven.

Comment: why do you want to hide the parameters?

Comment: @Yashua nothing more than making it look cool, the page never gets reloaded so why should he user see links changing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if your app is ajax then the url won't change. You can also wrap the entire thing in an iframe and only navigate inner frame. But keep in mind that this is generally bad practice as history and bookmarks don't work.